# Why The Template of template function is invalid in Visual C++

Tags: c++, templates

I find it is invalid to use the template of template function in Visual C++ 2013.
First I defined a template function pointer (which is used to convert from T to string):

```
template<class T>
struct TemplateFn
{
    typedef string(*T2STRING)(T);
};
```

And then I defined another template function

```
 template<class T>
 vector<string> Vector2StringVector(vector<T> a_vt, TemplateFn<T>::T2STRING a_fn)
 {
    auto vtString = vector<string>();
    for (auto i = a_vt.begin(); i != a_vt.end(); i++)
    {
        vtString.push_back(a_fn(*i));
    }
    return vtString;
 }
```

And the compiler will output an error:  C2061 SYNTAX ERROR: IDENTIFIER 'T2STRING'
Finally I just change the codes to the below:

```
 template<class T>
 vector<string> Vector2StringVector(vector<T> a_vt, string(*T2STRING)(T))
 {
     auto vtString = vector<string>();
     for (auto i = a_vt.begin(); i != a_vt.end(); i++)
     {
         vtString.push_back(T2STRING(*i));
     }
     return vtString;
 }
```

And that's all right.
So it is so wired to me. Is there a elegant way to use this way likes TemplateFn::T2STRING ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T2STRING is a dependent nested type, so you should give the compiler a hint. Change your function header into

```
 vector<string> Vector2StringVector(vector<T> a_vt, typename TemplateFn<T>::T2STRING a_fn)
```

BTW, don't you try to reimplement `std::transform` (with additional `std::back_inserter`)?